# Snail Algorithm - controlling Max/Min position for traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, list, refactoring, traversal

I'm working on a problem in CodeWars for fun, and I'm having trouble with a couple of things:

1. Understanding where I need to modify the code in order to properly control the "turning point" of m and n so that they begin decreasing rather than increasing.
2. Refactoring this code appropriately.

The purpose of the algorithm is to traverse a 2D list like a "snail", e.g.

```
    [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
```

should return

```
[1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]
```

for any list of size n*n

I don't have a strong background in math or CS, but I really love both and try to understand these problems with depth.

I know, for example, that if `n` represents the rows and `m` represents the columns of the 2D list, I need to increase the minimum `n`  by 1 for each "circuit" of the snail, and decrease the maximum `m` for each circuit, but I'm having trouble understanding where that needs to happen.

I have looked at some recursive solutions briefly, but before I started delving into those, I was hoping someone could take a look at this and help me understand where my thinking is totally *wrong*.

```py
def snail(array):

    new_snail = []
    n,m = 0,0
    j = 1



    while j <= len(array):
        print(n,m)
        if n == 0 and m == 0:

            while m < len(array)-j:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                m += 1

            while n < len(array)-j:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                n += 1

        else:

            while m > 0:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                m -= 1

            while n > 0:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                n -= 1
            m += 1
            n += 1
        j+=1
    return new_snail
```

The output of this algorithm on a 3x3 2D list is presently 
`[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 4]`, meaning I am moving backwards after reaching the end.

On a larger 2D list of 4x4,

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],
         [4,5,6,7],
         [8,9,10,11],
         [12,13,14,15]]
```

the output is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 15, 14, 13, 12, 8, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4]`, so I am going back and forth on the 1st row.

Thanks for taking a look, and I hope this falls within the guidelines for a SO question.  I care less about getting points for the exercise/getting it right and more about understanding why my code is wrong/poor practice.

**Update**

I'm understanding the problem better, I believe, and have made some progress, but what is killing me is still the bounds of the list.  I feel like I'm really weak on that.  I end up going too far in one direction, and all of my solutions for that are really hamfisted.

```py
def snail(array):
    new_snail = []
    visited = "*"
    i,j = 0,0

    current_dir = "right"

    def change_dir(direction):
        if direction == "right":
            return "down"
        elif direction == "down":
            return "left"
        elif direction == "left":
            return "up"
        elif direction == "up":
            return "right"

    def move(ipos,jpos,direction):
        i,j = ipos,jpos
        if i == -1:
            i += 1
        elif i == len(array):
            i -= 1
        elif j == -1:
            j +=1
        elif j == len(array):
            j -= 1

        if direction == "right":
            return i, j+1
        elif direction == "down":
            return i+1, j
        elif direction == "left":
            return i, j-1
        elif direction == "up":
            return i-1, j    


    new_snail.append(array[0][0])
    array[0][0] = "*"

    while len(new_snail) < len(array)**2:
        i,j = move(i,j,current_dir)

        if 0 <= i <= len(array)-1 and 0 <= j <= len(array)-1:
            if array[i][j] != visited:
                new_snail.append(array[i][j])
                array[i][j] = "*"
            else:
                current_dir = change_dir(current_dir)                
        else:
            current_dir = change_dir(current_dir)

    return new_snail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll only provide an idea and code should be written by yourself.

There are four directions the snail heads to, in order, right(j += 1), down(i += 1), left(j -= 1), up(i -= 1).

Snail will go by these four directions on circle(right, down, left, up, right, down, left...) , turn into next direction util reach the border or the number visited. And ends when the snail can not walk to any grid.

The definition of `can not walk to any grid`: can not step into next grid in the direction and in next direction.

Sample code with comment

```
directions = [
    lambda i, j: (i, j + 1),
    lambda i, j: (i + 1, j),
    lambda i, j: (i, j - 1),
    lambda i, j: (i - 1, j),
]

array = [[1,2,3,4],
         [4,5,6,7],
         [8,9,10,11],
         [12,13,14,15]]

def in_matrix(i, j):
    return 0 <= i < len(array) and 0 <= j < len(array)

def is_visited(i, j):
    return array[i][j] == 0


def snail(array):
    direction_cnt = 0
    i, j = 0, 0
    ret = []
    ret.append(array[i][j])
    array[i][j] = 0  # mark as visited
    while True:
        direction_func = directions[direction_cnt % 4]  # turning directions in circle
        tmp_i, tmp_j = direction_func(i, j)  # attempt to head one step
        if (not in_matrix(tmp_i, tmp_j)) or is_visited(tmp_i, tmp_j):  # over border or visted
            direction_cnt += 1  # change direction
        else:
            i, j = tmp_i, tmp_j  # confirm this step
            ret.append(array[i][j])
            array[i][j] = 0  # mark as visited
            if len(ret) == len(array)**2:  # simple terminal criteria
                return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print snail(array)
```

Comment: Thank you, I originally had this idea but then a math buddy of mine looked at it, and I went after it differently mentally.  I feel like I could easily mark visited by simply putting an ```*``` in place of a visited element (similar to pathfinding stuff), and then the border will be close in every time we complete a circuit.

Do I need to use recursion here?  I'm still learning on that front.

Comment: You _could_ do it using recursion, but in this case a straight-forward iterative approach will make it easier. The idea to 'flag' visited elements is indeed a good one, that can make your code shorter and simpler.

Comment: no recursion, just go ahead by the rule. In the 4x4 matrix, once you reach number 4,  turn into right(after up direction, in circle), just go ahead

Comment: @HolaYang I'm still stuck on the visited part.  I don't know how to combine checking if something is visited with checking if we're within the actual list without getting IndexErrors.

Comment: In the origin matrix, after reach a number, change it to 0 (mark it as visited). As to check if we are in the matrix (not over the border), 0<=i,j<=n. Check if we are in the matrix at first, and check visited secondly. You can do it.

Comment: @QuincyTennyson I gave my implementation as reference if you have finished your code.

Comment: I did end up finishing, and when I broke it out into functions I was able to reason about it more easily.  However, I did end up using @m.raynal's suggestion of a "fence" around the matrix.  I really appreciate you replying here, because I see now that I was simply off a bit in my positioning of the logic.  This is also a great example of using lambda functions, and I will without a doubt remember that for next time.  Thank you for sticking with me!

Comment: Note that the 'fence' thing works well on a toy project with pedagogic purpose, but would be seen as a 'heresy' in production code for a real-world project. Checking for bounds is the way to go in general, rather than modifying an object we're only supposed to observe.

Comment: Hi @HolaYang. Your solution seems very interesting, however, after implementing the same exact code in codewars, I can pass the tests, but it gives a time-out error. Has anyone else used this code to submit an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question about "what is wrong":

```
        else:

            while m > 0:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                m -= 1

            while n > 0:
                new_snail.append(array[n][m])
                n -= 1
            m += 1
            n += 1
        j+=1
```

On this part, you tell the interpreter "M is 1" (actually, m = 0 +1, but it's the same result)
And then you say "if M is not == 0 (the else case), m = m -1"

So, on the first iteraction after j+=1, m is 1, and goes to the second case, making it go backwards.

You could re-write that "m > 0" as "m > j" instead, since you increase J by 1 on every cycle.

Edit:
The first part of your condition should also be re-written as "m == j and n == j", instead of 0. Otherwise, it will ALWAYS go to the second case after the first iteraction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to do it, taking in consideration that you talked about refactoring the code. So there are a few points that can help you seeing this problem under a different light.
First we set a few things: directions, and the next direction to take for the snail. Since the directions go in a cycle (right, down, left, up, right, down ...), we can represent that with a function, `next_direction`. 
Also, creating a function that simply 'updates' a position can make the code easier to read.

```
RIGHT = 0
DOWN = 1
LEFT = 2
UP = 3
NB_DIRECTIONS = 4


def next_direction(direction):
    return (direction + 1) % NB_DIRECTIONS


def update_position(position, direction):
    x, y = position
    if direction == RIGHT:
        return x + 1, y
    elif direction == DOWN:
        return x, y + 1
    elif direction == LEFT:
        return x - 1, y
    elif direction == UP:
        return x, y - 1
```

Then the functions to get the value from the array and to set a value in the array as 'visited'.

```
def get_value(array, position):
    x, y = position
    return array[y][x]


def set_as_visited(array, position):
    x, y = position
    array[y][x] = '*'


def is_visited(array, position):
    return get_value(array, position) == '*'
```

And the 'main' function. I used your idea in a comment to replace by `'*'` the places that had been visited in the array. Since we do this, instead of checking for bounds, we can surround the whole matrix with `'*'`.

```
def snail_arr(array):
    # compute the array size
    array_size = len(array) * len(array[0])

    # surround the array of '*'
    array = [['*' for _ in range(len(array[0]) + 2)]] + [
        ['*'] + array[i] + ['*']
        for i in range(len(array))
    ] + [['*' for _ in range(len(array[0]) + 2)]]

    # initialize position and direction
    position = 1, 1
    direction = RIGHT

    result = [get_value(array, position)]
    set_as_visited(array, position)
    nb_visited = 1

    while nb_visited < array_size:
        new_position = update_position(position, direction)
        if not is_visited(array, new_position):
            result += [get_value(array, new_position)]
            set_as_visited(array, new_position)
            position = new_position
            nb_visited += 1
        else:
            direction = next_direction(direction)
    return result
```

You can test it:

```
array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(snail_arr(array))  
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10]
```

Edit:
To do it with the array bounds, you can add a new function to check:

```
def is_in_bounds(array, position):  # valid only for square array
    x, y = position
    array_size = len(array)
    return (0 <= x < array_size) and (0 <= y < array_size)
```

Then the condition `if not is_visited(array, new_position):` can be replaced by `if is_in_bounds(array, new_position)` in the code.

Comment: I am getting very close, but I was hesitant to do mine without using the list bounds simply because I feel like it's stealing a key part of your solution.  How would it look with bounds?  Here is what I've got so far... https://gist.github.com/qetennyson/fb2862aee5b01d2074f5fd61f2467bd5

Comment: Thank you!  I finally got it working when I broke it out into functions (what is comical, is that I would do this with an application I'm writing, but when I solve these problems I'm still in scripting mode :D)

Comment: Actually, breaking the code into functions can help a lot, and is often considered (to a certain extent) a good practice. The whole thing I wrote could easily be 3 times shorter and still compute correct results, but sometimes a longer, better organized code can be a gain of time (debugging, maintaining, modifying ....).

Comment: Absolutely, and maybe I was not clear.  My meaning is that the act of structuring the program transformed my thinking for the better.  I do have a habit of properly structuring programs that I would write for a legitimate purpose.  However, for these little challenge problems, my mind reverts to when I first learned Python/programming and I just write walls of ugly code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is spiral order matrix traversal-Efficient way to traverse a matric using direction=

```
vector<int> Solution::spiralOrder(const vector<vector<int>> &arr) {

int r = arr.size();
int c = arr[0].size();

int left = 0;
int right = c-1;

int top = 0;
int bottom = r-1;
int dir = 0;
vector<int> ans;

while(left <= right && top <= bottom){
      
    if(dir == 0){
        for(int i = left; i<=right; i++){
            ans.push_back(arr[top][i]);
        }
        top++;
        dir = 1;
    }
    else if(dir == 1){
        for(int i = top; i<=bottom; i++){
            ans.push_back(arr[i][right]);
        }
        right--;
        dir = 2;
    }
    else if(dir == 2){
        for(int i = right; i>=left; i--){
            ans.push_back(arr[bottom][i]);
        }
        bottom--;
        dir = 3;
    }
    else if(dir == 3){
        for(int i = bottom; i>=top; i--){
            ans.push_back(arr[i][left]);
        }
        left++;;
        dir = 0;
    }
}

return ans;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
public class Snails {

    public static int getLoopFactor(int n) {
        return (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
    }

    public static List<Integer> MatrixCorner(int[][] matrix, int startPosition) {
        int verify = 0;
        var result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        var reverse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // first row
        for (int i = startPosition; i < matrix.length - startPosition; i++) {
            for (int j = startPosition; j < matrix.length - startPosition; j++) {
                result.add(matrix[i][j]);
                verify++;
            }
            break;
        }
        // last column
        for (int i = startPosition + 1; i < matrix.length - startPosition - 1; i++) {
            result.add(matrix[i][matrix.length - startPosition - 1]);
        }

        if (verify > 1) {
            // last row reversed
            for (int i = matrix.length - 1 - startPosition; i < matrix.length - startPosition; i++) {
                for (int j = startPosition; j < matrix.length - startPosition; j++) {
                    reverse.add(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                Collections.reverse(reverse);
                result.addAll(reverse);
                reverse.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        //first column  reversed
        for (int i = startPosition + 1; i < matrix.length - startPosition - 1; i++) {
            reverse.add(matrix[i][startPosition]);
        }
        Collections.reverse(reverse);
        result.addAll(reverse);
        reverse.clear();
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] snail(int[][] array) {
        if (array.length == 0 || array[0].length == 0) return new int[]{};
        List<Integer> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();
        int k = getLoopFactor(array.length);
        int check = 0;
        while (check <= k) {
            finalResult.addAll(MatrixCorner(array, check));
            check++;
        }
        return finalResult.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.